# How to hide column in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to know if it is possible to hide the column in JasperReports if the column contains no data.

Comment: Can you please explain what you have tried so that others in the community can help you from there on.

Comment: @RozieRozack Do you want to avoid using java API?

Comment: For exp. i have the data shows below:                                                                                Year
Types of Car 2009 2010 2011
Toyota  1 
Honda  0 
Suzuki  1 
Total         2                                                   if i choose the data for year 2009(key in parameter), then the data for that year will appear, for others contains no data, so i want to hide the column for year 2010 and 2011. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can use the crosstab, for example

Answer (score -1):

Check the property of that column in Ireport whether "Remove Line when Blank" option is check or uncheck. using this property u can hide that column

Comment: Your answer is about how to hide row, not the column